# How to set Temporary Files to a relative path?

Tags: blend-files, saving

The backup files are only stored if I replace *Temporary files* path `//` with e.g. `/blenderFileLocation/`. Otherwise I get permission denied errors. Any ideas where to start searching the cause?

Answer (score 1):

The double slash implies "relative to the blend file".  Until the first time you save the blend file, Blender treats that as "the current working directory" -- meaning the directory you were in when you started Blender.  After you save the blend file it becomes the directory you wrote the blend fire to.

If you are getting permission denied errors, it usually means that you don't have write access to the directory you're working in.  This is often because you invoked Blender through an icon and the OS has set up Blender's installation directory as the current working directory.

So, either always save the blend file before you start changing it or do as you're doing and set a preference for the save directory.  There's a good reason to always save first: if you use external files, like image files, and are using relative paths, then Blender won't know what the relative path is if you open the image file before you have saved your blend file.